# preprocessing data before GaussianNB for categorical for numerical features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

- I'm using GaussianNB for classification problem
- all the features are numerical and they represent marks about something  (every mark is between 1 and 8 and they are results to exams)

The algorithm seems to work enough well in my case: I got 0,85 as an accuracy score.
But I read that Gaussian should have mean 0 and variance 1 but they don't.
Should I use a scaler such as Standard Scaler before?
Is it compulsory in my case?
I tried it but performances didn't go up

Comment: "*I read that Gaussian should have mean 0 and variance 1 but they don't*", as is, means absolutely nothing here. Where did you read it and what is its relation with your specific context? Gaussian is a very general term, and on itself it means nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Probably, I got confused. However, the article said that features should be continuous and not discrete beacuse for discrete ones the multinomial NB approach is better, is it correct?

Comment: Please notice that SO does not work by one-liner questions in the comments out of context; neither it is a tutorial service. Please take the time to post a well-formulated question, citing your research so far and your specific issue. For non-coding ML questions, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are more appropriate fora

Comment: OK, sorry I'm new here, I'll learn how to write better posts. Thank you for you suggestions

Comment: You are welcome; please be sure to go through the help system, especially [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

The 'standard Gaussian'- which is the basic/hypothetical Gaussian distribution - has its mean at 0 and its variance at 1. For example people's height around the world has mean of 175cm and variance of 10cm, yet it is still Gaussian (bell shaped).